# Editing profiles in arch linux

Tags: archlinux

I am very new to Arch Linux and have chrooted into the system. I screwed up the wireless profile, but have fixed them in netctl. How do I write to the file and exit out of the text editor that is prompted for you to edit the file?

Answer (score 0):

To write to the file:
    sudo nano /path/to/file

And to exit from the nano text editor press Control X.

Then Y to confirm save and exit, and enter to commit the save.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of editor has been opened. Which you can set in the .bashrc file.
If it is nano press ctrl+o to save the changes and ctrl+x to quit
If it is vi or vim, Goto command mode by pressing escape. Then type :wq to write and press enter.
If you are not able to make out between the two, just check if it has shortcut key info at the bottom of the page, if yes. It is nano or else it is vi.
PS: Since you are new the arch linux I assumed that you have not installed any other CLI based editors.